# How do I change selected text color with user color picker?

Tags: jquery, text, colors, selectedindex

I am using the [color picker plugin](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/452401/ColorPicker-a-jQuery-UI-Widget) and want to change the selected text color.

Here is where I need to change the selected text color. How would I do that?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://inzerciatop.sk/css/24.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://inzerciatop.sk/css/evol.colorpicker.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://inzerciatop.sk/css/evol.colorpicker.css" />


   <input style="width:100px;" id="mycolor"   class="colorPicker evo-cp0" />


<div id="title"  contenteditable="true" >bbbhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</div>
```

Comment: it's working well for me, what's the problem? the colour of the text changes accordingly to the colour picker

Comment: The user selected that part of the text, and he chose the color from color picker , how to work in cms editor.I do not speak English

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean